# YAML load for chained file handles

Tags: python, yaml, python-itertools

PyYAML makes loading a `.yml` document trivial.

```
config = yaml.load(open('myconfig.yml', 'r'))
```

I have a list of YAML file names `filelist`, and I'm trying to come up with a concise Pythonic way of loading them together (treating them as a single document). This is what I tried.

```
fhlist = [open(filename, 'r') for filename in filelist]
cfginput = itertools.chain(*fhlist)
config = yaml.load(cfginput)
```

However, this is causing an exception.

```
AttributeError: 'itertools.chain' object has no attribute 'read'
```

What am I doing wrong? Is there a simple solution to the task I'm trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I assume `loading them together` means either read them all, or merging them:

#### Read them all

```
yamls = []
for filename in filelist:
    with open(filename) as f:
        yamls.append(yaml.load(f))
```

#### Merge them all

```
yamls = {}
for filename in filelist:
    with open(filename) as f:
        yamls.update(yaml.load(f))
```

*Notice: This will overwrite properties with same keys, and is not recursive.*

**Edit:** If you want to concat all files and read them after as yaml:

```
content = ''
for filename in filelist:
    with open(filename) as f:
        content += f.read()
result = yaml.load(content)
```

*This will probably get the same result as merging the yaml dicts...*

Comment: The **Merge them all** suggestion works beautifully and simply. So simple, in fact, that I'm embarrassed I didn't think of it myself. Thanks!